# Javascript/jQuery war card game

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am making a game of war and I need help. Here are the specifications:

Deal Button

The deal button, when clicked, will start the game.

If this is the first time the player is playing the game, the game will prompt the user for their name. (The user is not prompted to enter their name with future consecutive games.)

Once the name is added the program will:

- Add the player’s name to the board (on the left) and to the score
  area.
- Any score that exists is to be cleared out.
- Use the random number function to deal the cards from the deck evenly
  between the two players to create a hand array for each.
- You will need to keep track of the cards dealt from the deck to assure
  there are no duplicates.

Once the cards are dealt:

Clear any ‘Card Count’ that may be displayed on the board and put in the
number 26 as the new ‘Card Count’.

Play Button

When the Play button is clicked, the player receives a card. One half second
later Slick receives a card.
NOTE: Start at the beginning of each players hand array and
systematically move through the array to display one card for each turn.
For each successive turn, use the next card in each of the hand arrays.
For each hand played the Card Count will decrease by 1.
Once the cards for that turn are played, the two cards are compared for highest
‘deck value’. Card with the highest ‘deck value’ wins.
Points from BOTH cards are added to the score of the player holding the
card of highest ‘deck value’.
Low card player gets no points for that play.
After each player has discarded all of his/her 26 cards, the game will end. The
winner will be the one with the highest accumulated score from the cards they
have won.
Place a red X in the loser’s box and the green check mark in the winner’s
box.
If you are playing again with the same players, then click ‘Deal’.
The game starts over with a new deal and zero points.
The ‘Deal’ will not prompt for a new name if a name had already been
entered into the game for ‘Player’.
The code used for the player’s and Slick’s hands, as well as the used
cards, is cleared out.
The ‘Card Count’ is set to 26.
If you are playing with a new player’s name then click ‘New Player’.
See ‘New Player Button’ below for instructions on how the ‘New Player’
Button works.

New Player Button

Clicking this button starts the game over with a new deal, zero points, and
prompted for a new player’s name. (There is no need to click ‘Deal’.)
The code used for the player’s and Slick’s hands, as well as the used
cards, is cleared out.
The ‘Card Count’ is set to 26.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Card Game</title>
    <link href="styles/normalilze.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles/my_style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="main">
        <h1> Card Game </h1>
        <div id="left">

            <div id="pHand">
                <br />
                <!-- Using JavaScript replace the word 'Player' with the name of
            the person playing the game-->
                <h2 class="pName">Player</h2>
            </div>
            <div id="cHand">
                <h2>Slick</h2>
            </div>
            <div id="but">
                <button id="newPlayer">New player</button>
                <button id="deal">Deal</button>
                <button id="play">Play</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id='right'>
            <h2>Card Count:</h2>
            <!-- Using JavaSCript enter the number of remaining cards in the 'Players' hand
            in the p tag below-->
            <p id="cardCount"></p>
            <br />
            <!-- Using JavaSCript replace the word 'Player' with the name of
            the person playing the game-->
            <h2 class="pName">Player</h2>
            <h2 id="pName2">:</h2>
            <!-- Using jQuery insert the current 'Player' score in the p tag
             below -->
            <p id="pScore"></p>
            <br />
            <h2 id="cName">Slick:</h2>
            <!-- Using jQuery insert the current 'Slick' score in the p tag
             below -->
            <p id="cScore"></p>

            <!-- add and style winning message in the
             following div -->
            <div id="win"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jQ-War.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

    $(document).ready(function () {

  $('#deal').click(function(){
    var player = prompt("Please enter your name.");
    if (player != null) {
      document.getElementsByClassName('pName').innerHTML = player;
    }
  });

  var used_cards = new Array();
  var player_cards = new Array();
  var slick_cards = new Array();
  var P_hand = {
    cards: new Array()
  }
  var S_hand = {
    cards: new Array()
  }
  var Hand = {
    cards: new Array(),
  }

  var deck = [
    new card('Ace', 'Hearts', 11, 142),
    new card('Two', 'Hearts', 2, 22),
    new card('Three', 'Hearts', 3, 32),
    new card('Four', 'Hearts', 4, 42),
    new card('Five', 'Hearts', 5, 52),
    new card('Six', 'Hearts', 6, 62),
    new card('Seven', 'Hearts', 7, 72),
    new card('Eight', 'Hearts', 8, 82),
    new card('Nine', 'Hearts', 9, 92),
    new card('Ten', 'Hearts', 10, 102),
    new card('Jack', 'Hearts', 10, 112),
    new card('Queen', 'Hearts', 10, 122),
    new card('King', 'Hearts', 10, 132),
    new card('Ace', 'Diamonds', 11, 141),
    new card('Two', 'Diamonds', 2, 21),
    new card('Three', 'Diamonds', 3, 31),
    new card('Four', 'Diamonds', 4, 41),
    new card('Five', 'Diamonds', 5, 51),
    new card('Six', 'Diamonds', 6, 61),
    new card('Seven', 'Diamonds', 7, 71),
    new card('Eight', 'Diamonds', 8, 81),
    new card('Nine', 'Diamonds', 9, 91),
    new card('Ten', 'Diamonds', 10, 101),
    new card('Jack', 'Diamonds', 10, 111),
    new card('Queen', 'Diamonds', 10, 121),
    new card('King', 'Diamonds', 10, 131),
    new card('Ace', 'Clubs', 11, 143),
    new card('Two', 'Clubs', 2, 23),
    new card('Three', 'Clubs', 3, 33),
    new card('Four', 'Clubs', 4, 43),
    new card('Five', 'Clubs', 5, 53),
    new card('Six', 'Clubs', 6, 63),
    new card('Seven', 'Clubs', 7, 73),
    new card('Eight', 'Clubs', 8, 83),
    new card('Nine', 'Clubs', 9, 93),
    new card('Ten', 'Clubs', 10, 103),
    new card('Jack', 'Clubs', 10, 113),
    new card('Queen', 'Clubs', 10, 123),
    new card('King', 'Clubs', 10, 133),
    new card('Ace', 'Spades', 11, 144),
    new card('Two', 'Spades', 2, 24),
    new card('Three', 'Spades', 3, 34),
    new card('Four', 'Spades', 4, 44),
    new card('Five', 'Spades', 5, 54),
    new card('Six', 'Spades', 6, 64),
    new card('Seven', 'Spades', 7, 74),
    new card('Eight', 'Spades', 8, 84),
    new card('Nine', 'Spades', 9, 94),
    new card('Ten', 'Spades', 10, 104),
    new card('Jack', 'Spades', 10, 114),
    new card('Queen', 'Spades', 10, 124),
    new card('King', 'Spades', 10, 134)
  ];

  function card(name, suit, value, trump) {
    this.name = name;
    this.suit = suit;
    this.value = value;
    this.trump = trump;
  }
});
```

So far the deal button shows a prompt and when I enter in text it does not change the classes text to what was entered, and I am having trouble making the hand arrays and making them non repeatable random arrays. Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Tony,

document.getElementsByClassName() returns an array-like collection of found elements. So If your collection contains only 1 item -  with class 'pName', you need to address it as an array element with index 0.

also, maybe you have a typo in jquery import:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('#deal').click(function(){
    var player = prompt("Please enter your name.");
    if (player != null) {
      document.getElementsByClassName('pName')[0].innerHTML = player;
    }
  });

  var used_cards = new Array();
  var player_cards = new Array();
  var slick_cards = new Array();
  var P_hand = {
    cards: new Array()
  }
  var S_hand = {
    cards: new Array()
  }
  var Hand = {
    cards: new Array(),
  }

  var deck = [
    new card('Ace', 'Hearts', 11, 142),
    new card('Two', 'Hearts', 2, 22),
    new card('Three', 'Hearts', 3, 32),
    new card('Four', 'Hearts', 4, 42),
    new card('Five', 'Hearts', 5, 52),
    new card('Six', 'Hearts', 6, 62),
    new card('Seven', 'Hearts', 7, 72),
    new card('Eight', 'Hearts', 8, 82),
    new card('Nine', 'Hearts', 9, 92),
    new card('Ten', 'Hearts', 10, 102),
    new card('Jack', 'Hearts', 10, 112),
    new card('Queen', 'Hearts', 10, 122),
    new card('King', 'Hearts', 10, 132),
    new card('Ace', 'Diamonds', 11, 141),
    new card('Two', 'Diamonds', 2, 21),
    new card('Three', 'Diamonds', 3, 31),
    new card('Four', 'Diamonds', 4, 41),
    new card('Five', 'Diamonds', 5, 51),
    new card('Six', 'Diamonds', 6, 61),
    new card('Seven', 'Diamonds', 7, 71),
    new card('Eight', 'Diamonds', 8, 81),
    new card('Nine', 'Diamonds', 9, 91),
    new card('Ten', 'Diamonds', 10, 101),
    new card('Jack', 'Diamonds', 10, 111),
    new card('Queen', 'Diamonds', 10, 121),
    new card('King', 'Diamonds', 10, 131),
    new card('Ace', 'Clubs', 11, 143),
    new card('Two', 'Clubs', 2, 23),
    new card('Three', 'Clubs', 3, 33),
    new card('Four', 'Clubs', 4, 43),
    new card('Five', 'Clubs', 5, 53),
    new card('Six', 'Clubs', 6, 63),
    new card('Seven', 'Clubs', 7, 73),
    new card('Eight', 'Clubs', 8, 83),
    new card('Nine', 'Clubs', 9, 93),
    new card('Ten', 'Clubs', 10, 103),
    new card('Jack', 'Clubs', 10, 113),
    new card('Queen', 'Clubs', 10, 123),
    new card('King', 'Clubs', 10, 133),
    new card('Ace', 'Spades', 11, 144),
    new card('Two', 'Spades', 2, 24),
    new card('Three', 'Spades', 3, 34),
    new card('Four', 'Spades', 4, 44),
    new card('Five', 'Spades', 5, 54),
    new card('Six', 'Spades', 6, 64),
    new card('Seven', 'Spades', 7, 74),
    new card('Eight', 'Spades', 8, 84),
    new card('Nine', 'Spades', 9, 94),
    new card('Ten', 'Spades', 10, 104),
    new card('Jack', 'Spades', 10, 114),
    new card('Queen', 'Spades', 10, 124),
    new card('King', 'Spades', 10, 134)
  ];

  function card(name, suit, value, trump) {
    this.name = name;
    this.suit = suit;
    this.value = value;
    this.trump = trump;
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Card Game</title>
    <link href="styles/normalilze.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles/my_style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="main">
        <h1> Card Game </h1>
        <div id="left">

            <div id="pHand">
                <br />
                <!-- Using JavaScript replace the word 'Player' with the name of
            the person playing the game-->
                <h2 class="pName">Player</h2>
            </div>
            <div id="cHand">
                <h2>Slick</h2>
            </div>
            <div id="but">
                <button id="newPlayer">New player</button>
                <button id="deal">Deal</button>
                <button id="play">Play</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id='right'>
            <h2>Card Count:</h2>
            <!-- Using JavaSCript enter the number of remaining cards in the 'Players' hand
            in the p tag below-->
            <p id="cardCount"></p>
            <br />
            <!-- Using JavaSCript replace the word 'Player' with the name of
            the person playing the game-->
            <h2 class="pName">Player</h2>
            <h2 id="pName2">:</h2>
            <!-- Using jQuery insert the current 'Player' score in the p tag
             below -->
            <p id="pScore"></p>
            <br />
            <h2 id="cName">Slick:</h2>
            <!-- Using jQuery insert the current 'Slick' score in the p tag
             below -->
            <p id="cScore"></p>

            <!-- add and style winning message in the
             following div -->
            <div id="win"> </div>


        </div>



    </div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jQ-War.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I was able to display the player name for the deal and new player button. I am having troubles with the arrays and I do not know where to start.

Comment: Alexey, I need help with the scoring and making the cards not repeat. I was able to figure out how to make an array for the player and computer, but the cards that are displayed are repeating. Here is the JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jze79d64/

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('#deal').click(function(){
    var player = prompt("Please enter your name.");
    if (player != null) {
      document.getElementsByClassName('pName')[0].innerHTML = player;
    }
  });

  var used_cards = new Array();
  var player_cards = new Array();
  var slick_cards = new Array();
  var P_hand = {
    cards: new Array()
  }
  var S_hand = {
    cards: new Array()
  }
  var Hand = {
    cards: new Array(),
  }

  var deck = [
    new card('Ace', 'Hearts', 11, 142),
    new card('Two', 'Hearts', 2, 22),
    new card('Three', 'Hearts', 3, 32),
    new card('Four', 'Hearts', 4, 42),
    new card('Five', 'Hearts', 5, 52),
    new card('Six', 'Hearts', 6, 62),
    new card('Seven', 'Hearts', 7, 72),
    new card('Eight', 'Hearts', 8, 82),
    new card('Nine', 'Hearts', 9, 92),
    new card('Ten', 'Hearts', 10, 102),
    new card('Jack', 'Hearts', 10, 112),
    new card('Queen', 'Hearts', 10, 122),
    new card('King', 'Hearts', 10, 132),
    new card('Ace', 'Diamonds', 11, 141),
    new card('Two', 'Diamonds', 2, 21),
    new card('Three', 'Diamonds', 3, 31),
    new card('Four', 'Diamonds', 4, 41),
    new card('Five', 'Diamonds', 5, 51),
    new card('Six', 'Diamonds', 6, 61),
    new card('Seven', 'Diamonds', 7, 71),
    new card('Eight', 'Diamonds', 8, 81),
    new card('Nine', 'Diamonds', 9, 91),
    new card('Ten', 'Diamonds', 10, 101),
    new card('Jack', 'Diamonds', 10, 111),
    new card('Queen', 'Diamonds', 10, 121),
    new card('King', 'Diamonds', 10, 131),
    new card('Ace', 'Clubs', 11, 143),
    new card('Two', 'Clubs', 2, 23),
    new card('Three', 'Clubs', 3, 33),
    new card('Four', 'Clubs', 4, 43),
    new card('Five', 'Clubs', 5, 53),
    new card('Six', 'Clubs', 6, 63),
    new card('Seven', 'Clubs', 7, 73),
    new card('Eight', 'Clubs', 8, 83),
    new card('Nine', 'Clubs', 9, 93),
    new card('Ten', 'Clubs', 10, 103),
    new card('Jack', 'Clubs', 10, 113),
    new card('Queen', 'Clubs', 10, 123),
    new card('King', 'Clubs', 10, 133),
    new card('Ace', 'Spades', 11, 144),
    new card('Two', 'Spades', 2, 24),
    new card('Three', 'Spades', 3, 34),
    new card('Four', 'Spades', 4, 44),
    new card('Five', 'Spades', 5, 54),
    new card('Six', 'Spades', 6, 64),
    new card('Seven', 'Spades', 7, 74),
    new card('Eight', 'Spades', 8, 84),
    new card('Nine', 'Spades', 9, 94),
    new card('Ten', 'Spades', 10, 104),
    new card('Jack', 'Spades', 10, 114),
    new card('Queen', 'Spades', 10, 124),
    new card('King', 'Spades', 10, 134)
  ];

  function card(name, suit, value, trump) {
    this.name = name;
    this.suit = suit;
    this.value = value;
    this.trump = trump;
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Card Game</title>
    <link href="styles/normalilze.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles/my_style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="main">
        <h1> Card Game </h1>
        <div id="left">

            <div id="pHand">
                <br />
                <!-- Using JavaScript replace the word 'Player' with the name of
            the person playing the game-->
                <h2 class="pName">Player</h2>
            </div>
            <div id="cHand">
                <h2>Slick</h2>
            </div>
            <div id="but">
                <button id="newPlayer">New player</button>
                <button id="deal">Deal</button>
                <button id="play">Play</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id='right'>
            <h2>Card Count:</h2>
            <!-- Using JavaSCript enter the number of remaining cards in the 'Players' hand
            in the p tag below-->
            <p id="cardCount"></p>
            <br />
            <!-- Using JavaSCript replace the word 'Player' with the name of
            the person playing the game-->
            <h2 class="pName">Player</h2>
            <h2 id="pName2">:</h2>
            <!-- Using jQuery insert the current 'Player' score in the p tag
             below -->
            <p id="pScore"></p>
            <br />
            <h2 id="cName">Slick:</h2>
            <!-- Using jQuery insert the current 'Slick' score in the p tag
             below -->
            <p id="cScore"></p>

            <!-- add and style winning message in the
             following div -->
            <div id="win"> </div>


        </div>



    </div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jQ-War.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```